# Is accessing specific array indexes on a struct using an union undefined behavior?

Tags: c, unions

Consider the following C struct declaration containing types of animals

```
typedef enum Animals { DOG, CAT, LION, ELEPHANT, HIPPO } Animals;

typedef struct {
    union {
        struct {
            Animals pet; /*!< Pet animals are stored at index 0 */
            Animals zoo; /*!< Zoo animals are stored at index 1 */
        };
        Animals animals_list[2];
    };
} AnimalsList;
```

I'd like to access the animals sometimes using the `pet` member or `zoo` member and sometimes to iterate over all animals using `animals_list`. I am expecting that `pet` will always be at index 0 of `animals_list` and `zoo` to be always at index 1 of `animals_list`.

Is this assumption correct? Can this be considered undefined behavior? In particular I'm concerned about endianness difference across platforms.

I saw multiple questions regarding unions on stackoverflow but they all seems to use members of *different* size. My members have the *same size* and I'm trying to keep it that way.

Comment: You don't need a `union` for something that you want to access separately. Or is your intent just to understand the behaviour your described?

Comment: @jweyrich I just want to understand the behavior. But I am open to learn new ways of having both the iteration and individual members access. Maybe something easier to use/maintain than this union above?

Comment: This must have been asked before; can somebody find a duplicate. In summary: The C standard does not guarantee there will not be padding in the `struct`, but common C implementations will not, so the array will overlap the `struct` members as desired. Nonetheless, doing this is a bad idea.

Comment: This in no way answers your question, but storing information in the pointer itself is confusing; I would have a `struct Animal { enum Animals; enum Type; }` which stores twice as much, but is less confusing and more expandable. Then the number of pets and zoo animals doesn't have to be the same.

Comment: It's way safer, more readable and nicer to just write a proper api. `Animals *animals_get_pet(AnimalsList *t) { return &t->animals_list[0]; } Animals *animals_get_zoo(AnimalsList *t) { return &t->animals_list[1]; }`

Comment: @EricPostpischil Could please clarify why do you consider it a bad idea? I just put into production so this might be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this assumption correct? Can

Depends on the `sizeof Animals`. The compiler may choose to add extra padding between each member. You can hint the compiler to use a specific padding and use `_Static_assert` (C11) to make sure both sizes match:

```
_Static_assert(sizeof(animals_list) == 2 * sizeof(Animals), "Sizes don't match.")
```

The struct member order is specified by the standard, but the result of `offsetof(S, member)` is not.

Nevertheless, the possibly-existing-padding should be exactly the same between the anonymous struct members and between the `animals_list` items, so it most likely will work on any platform, but there are no guarantees from the language specification.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Standard, `arrayLValue[index]` is equivalent to `*(arrayLValue+index)`.  Neither gcc nor clang will allow for the possibility that an access to `*(someUnion.arrayMember+index)` might affect `someUnion`.  While gcc and clang seem to recognize that an access to `someUnion.arrayMember[index]` may affect `someUnion`, they only way that would be allowed to behave differently from the supposedly-equivalent `*(someUnion.arrayMember+index)` would be if the Standard didn't define the behavior of either.